# A service that turns doodles into PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I run a small business and need to create new PowerPoint presentations regularly.  I find this to be an enormous pain.  I'm not good at PowerPoint and creating PowerPoint is not part of my competitive advantage.

What I would like to do is draw out the slides, scan them, and send them to a service that converts my doodles to PowerPoint.  Is there such a service?

Comment: Hire an assistant or take on an intern?

Comment: @MarkM.  That is a possibility but I'm wondering if there is a service that will do this for me.

Answer (score 3):

> What I would like to do is draw out the slides, scan them, and send them to a service that converts my doodles to PowerPoint. Is there such a service?

No, I imagine that a service would have limited appeal. The skill required to create PowerPoints ranks somewhere between breathing and not getting your cock caught in your zipper.

Although, if you occassionally nip it when zipping the front of your jeans up, [try using OneNote to outline your presentation and then copy the outline into PowerPoint](http://www.onppt.com/note/onenote_article4.htm).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a fantastic idea to draw each slide by hand - you may even end up with a powerpoint presentation that is original and won't turn your audience off before you start...

It is easy to get your pictures into a presentation, there is a "photo album" option on the insert tab (it is available on older versions too but you need to be careful according to [this](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00050.htm).

So the problem is just one of getting your drawings into the computer as picture files. A cheap flatbed scanner is just a pain when scanning more than a couple of documents, but you may be more patient than me. You could get yourself a scanner with a feed mechanism, but these tend to be expensive compared to flatbed scanners. If you are not doing too many slides then there still exists [at least one](http://www.cclonline.com/product-info.asp?product_id=13689&category_id=72&manufacturer_id=0&tid=32100152101) manual feed scanner, having no lid will make it less of a pain than a normal flatbed scanner.

Or you could get yourself a graphics tablet and draw straight into the computer.